# Get difference of sums in single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have result from different request as an example.

1st req:

```
SELECT SUM(PRODUCT_QTY) FROM TABLEBLA
WHERE STATE='DONE' and  location_dest_id in (12,18) and location_id=5
```

gives:

```
sum(product_qty)
----------------
1200
```

2nd req:

```
SELECT SUM(PRODUCT_QTY) FROM TABLEBLA
WHERE STATE='CANCEL' and location_id (12,18) and location_dest_id=5
```

gives:

```
sum(product_qty)
----------------
900
```

I want to get the result as `1200-900 = 300`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 'DONE'  THEN PRODUCT_QTY ELSE 0 END) - 
SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 'CANCEL' THEN PRODUCT_QTY ELSE 0 END) 
 FROM TABLEBLA WHERE location_id IN (12,18) AND location_dest_id=5
```

Comment: verify there location they  switch cases in the two queries

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 'DONE' THEN PRODUCT_QTY ELSE - PRODUCT_QTY END)
FROM TABLEBLA 
WHERE STATE IN ('DONE', 'CANCEL') AND
      location_dest_id in (12, 18) and location_id = 5;
```

Or, if this is part of a larger query and you don't want the filtering in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 'DONE' THEN PRODUCT_QTY ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 'CANCEL' THEN PRODUCT_QTY END)
       ) as diff
FROM TABLEBLA
WHERE location_dest_id in (12, 18) and location_id = 5;
```

Comment: @m3asmi update where clause as `WHERE STATE IN ('DONE', 'CANCEL') AND location_dest_id IN (12,18) AND location_id=5` in first query and `WHERE location_dest_id IN (12,18) AND location_id=5` in second query

Comment: @gordon-linoff the verify there is to switch case